# Voltage Regulation to Brushless DC Motor

Tags: power-electronics, brushless-dc-motor

I am using a 12V brushless DC motor (peak current 4.6A) and I would like to have speed control over it.

Link to pump I am using: https://daviescraig.com.au/product/ebp40-electric-booster-pump-12v-9040/ebp40-electric-booster-pump-kit-12v-9040

After contacting the manufacturer, they informed me that I could accomplish speed control to some degree by reducing the pump input voltage as far down as 6V.

Currently, I am planning on using this high side switch: https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/MC33981.pdf

The switch allows for PWM output, which I have seen can be filtered to an analog output voltage - however I have not seen this done on high current inductive loads. Is this a feasible solution?

Another idea I had was regulating the output voltage of the high side switch using a switching regulator of some sort - not sure if this is a good solution either.

I'm looking for some guidance on which direction I go and if there are any other possibilities in achieving this goal.

Comment: What is your coil commutation speed and kV/RPM? I assume DCR=12V/4.6A Can you put on a tach? Or use Hall sensors as a Tach for a speed control?

Comment: Sorry if I didn't clarify in the post - the motor has an integrated motor control, so I am only dealing with supplying power to the external leads

Comment: Then show spec link

Comment: https://daviescraig.com.au/product/ebp40-electric-booster-pump-12v-9040/ebp40-electric-booster-pump-kit-12v-9040

Comment: upvote for contacting manufacturer before posting your question

Comment: Could you add info on the motor you are using? Is this a servomotor or a Stepper motor?

Comment: @Eduardo1992 it is a water pump, posted the link in the original post and above in the comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The switch allows for PWM output, which I have seen can be filtered to
>   an analog output voltage - however I have not seen this done on high
>   current inductive loads. Is this a feasible solution?

Probably not. The pump's built-in motor controller probably has a large filter capacitor across the supply to damp voltage spikes caused by lead inductance, so the load will look capacitive rather than inductive.

With simple switched PWM the capacitor will charge up to full supply voltage during the PWM 'on' time, and slowly discharge during the 'off' time. If PWM frequency is high the voltage will stay up between pulses and you won't get the desired speed control. To get an average of 6V the voltage must go down to zero between pulses, which may cause the pump controller to turn on and off rapidly, not turn on at all, or even blow up.

To smooth the PWM output you could add a diode and inductor, but the output voltage will vary depending on the load. To produce a stable output voltage you need to modify the PWM ratio according to the output voltage error. This is what a switching regulator does.

> Another idea I had was regulating the output voltage of the high side
>   switch using a switching regulator of some sort - not sure if this is
>   a good solution either.

This is actually what you need. Depending on the device, as well as varying the output  voltage you may also be able to turn it on and off with an 'enable' signal, and then you might not need the high-side switch.

Answer (score 0):

The internal motor controller should limit the starting current. If it doesn't, the selected input voltage controller appears to be capable of limiting the current. It appears to be capable of withstanding the typical stalled current of a motor with the 4.6 amp current rating. There does not appear to be any reason to regulate the output of the selected device.

The 6 V minimum input voltage recommended by the pump manufacturer should allow regulation of flow to 50% or less. The head capacity curve at half speed should run from half the head to half the capacity of the pump at full speed roughly parallel to the full-speed curve. The system system curve, particularly the static head will determine the flow at half speed.